# Select stament with division operator mysql using pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a table in my pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'CategoryCount': {0: 0, 1: 12, 2: 15, 3: 0, 4: 25, 5: 0},
        'frequency': {0: 123, 1: 234, 2: 456, 3: 678, 4: 890, 5: 145}
    })
```

---

```
+-----------------+-----------+
|  CategoryCount  | frequency |
+-----------------+-----------+
| 0               | 123       |
| 12              | 234       |
| 15              | 456       |
| 0               | 678       |
| 25              | 890       |
| 0               | 145       |
+-----------------+-----------+
```

it has 300 rows

I want to find total no. of Categorycount,where the frequency is less than 75%
i am writing this query in normal mysql to do so:

```
select count(CategoryCount) 
from category_analysis 
where (frequency * 100 / (select sum(frequency) from category_analysis)) < 75
```

how do i implement the same using python in pandas.

Comment: And, the expected output is?

Comment: @JohnGalt  |count(CategoryCount) |213|  is the output

Comment: IIUIC, `(df.frequency < df.frequency.sum() * 0.75 ).sum()` should probably work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC this would be Pandas equivalent (for 10%, because all your sample rows < 75%):

```
In [15]: df.frequency.sum()
Out[15]: 2526

In [16]: df.frequency / df.frequency.sum() < 0.1
Out[16]:
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
4    False
5     True
Name: frequency, dtype: bool

In [17]: df.loc[df.frequency / df.frequency.sum() < .1]
Out[17]:
   CategoryCount  frequency
0              0        123
1             12        234
5              0        145

In [18]: len(df.loc[df.frequency / df.frequency.sum() < .1])
Out[18]: 3
```

or a bit nicer [variant from @John Galt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471490/select-stament-with-division-operator-mysql-using-pandas-dataframe/40471673?noredirect=1#comment68187856_40471673):

```
In [19]: (df.frequency < df.frequency.sum() * 0.1 ).sum()
Out[19]: 3
```

OP's query in SQL:

[image]

Comment: `(df.frequency < df.frequency.sum() * 0.1 ).sum()` should do, instead of `.loc` setting.

Comment: @JohnGalt, yes, thank you! It definitely looks better!

Comment: @MaxU hey i didn't understand your taking 0.1(10%) how did u decided that?

and what if my rows instead of 300 would be more

Comment: @MaxU I finally understand where the mis-communication happened! I assumed there was a table prior to category_analysis in which Category existed as a column that we could perform value_counts on. That considered, my answer is totally incorrect. I'm glad I continued digging, and I'm glad you kept asking.

Comment: @piRSquared, could you undelete your answer - it's really great and can help others in future

Answer (score 2):

***note:*** This does not answer the OP's question.  However, as pointed out by @MaxU, it may be helpful for others.

use `value_counts` and `normalize`

```
df.CategoryCount.value_counts(normalize=True).lt(.75).sum()
```

Comment: It looks very nice, but it gives me completely different result set

Comment: @MaxU I took some liberties and guessed what OP wanted.  I'm ignoring their `frequency` column and assumed they calculated it with value counts or something similar.  My solution leverages those assumptions and gives a better implementation from the start.  If I guessed correctly, OP is fortunate considering the question was not clear.

Comment: @piRSquared hey, can i know where i could learn all these pandas advanced syntax? is there a website or a quick cheat sheet that i can refer to

Comment: @SRingne I responded the same way when someone else asked me the same question.  There is no better way to learn than "trial by fire".  Try to answer questions people post on SO.  Learn from MaxU, jezrael, EdChum, unutbu, Psidom, and many others as you try to be faster and better than them.  I thought I knew a lot before 6 months, ago.  I was fooling myself.  These people have taught me so much more that I anticipated.

Comment: @piRSquared appreciated sir! i too am a beginner to this data science field, and trying to learn as quickly as possible ! 
i'll surely take your advice

Comment: @piRSquared, i'm totally confused - OPs SQL query returns 3 (see a screenshot attached to my answer), your Pandas solution returns 4 and OP says it's exactly what they need :)

Comment: @MaxU I'm assuming OP's frequency column is incomplete.  They did not provide the requisite data to achieve the results they were looking for.  I ignored that column because I had made this assumption.  You can't know the `sum` without all the data.

Comment: @piRSquared, sure, but i was talking about the SQL - it'll definitely produce different result set. I guess the SQL is wrong...

Comment: @MaxU I finally understand where the mis-communication happened!  I assumed there was a table prior to `category_analysis` in which `Category` existed as a column that we could perform `value_counts` on.  That considered, my answer is totally incorrect.  I'm glad I continued digging, and I'm glad you kept asking.